# Data binding to bwu_datagrid

Tags: dart, bwu-datagrid

How can we make one-way data binding between `Map<int, SomeClass>` and Bwu_datagrid like https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/polymer-intro/#data-binding?
I would like to have Bwu_datagrid automatic display data from `Map<int, SomeClass>` without manual call `grid.invalidate();` if any `SomeClass` object in `Map<int, SomeClass>` had changes.

```
class SomeClass extends Object {
  int someClassId;
  String someClassName;
  String someClassDescr}
```

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many options. What you could do is to make `SomeClass` observable (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25111790/217408) and listen to changes of each instance and call `grid.invalidate()` when you receive an event.