# Flutter: How to use SharedPreferences synchronously?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I am using Shared Preferences in my Flutter app and what I would like to do is store `SharedPreferences` as a field on startup and then use it synchronously in the app. However I'm not sure if I'm not missing anything.
What I want to achieve is instead of:

```
method1() async {
  SharedPreferences sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return sp.getString('someKey');
}
```

to

```
SharedPreferences sp;
//I would probably pass SharedPreferences in constructor, but the idea is the same
someInitMethod() async {
  sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
}
method1() {
  return sp.getString('someKey');
}
method2() {
  return sp.getString('someKey2');
}
method3() {
  return sp.getString('someKey3');
}
```

In that way I would achieve synchronous access to sharedPrefs. Is it bad solution?

EDIT:
What is worth mentioning is that `getInstance` method will only check for instance and if there is any than it returns it, so as I see it, is that `async` is only needed to initialize instance. And both `set` and `get` methods are sync anyway.

```
static Future<SharedPreferences> getInstance() async {
  if (_instance == null) {
    final Map<String, Object> fromSystem =
        await _kChannel.invokeMethod('getAll');
    assert(fromSystem != null);
    // Strip the flutter. prefix from the returned preferences.
    final Map<String, Object> preferencesMap = <String, Object>{};
    for (String key in fromSystem.keys) {
      assert(key.startsWith(_prefix));
      preferencesMap[key.substring(_prefix.length)] = fromSystem[key];
    }
    _instance = new SharedPreferences._(preferencesMap);
  }
  return _instance;
}
```

Comment: There is no way to make a asynchronous API into a synchronous one.  Your example won't work because the return type of `await <expression>` is always `Future<result>` where `result` is the return type of `expression`.  Reading and writing from shared preferences can always fail - so you should be careful.

Comment: Where exactly you think it would not work? I don't think `await <expression>` returns `Future`. That's why we use `await`, don't we?

Comment: `await` is just sugar for `.then`.  The type of `sp` is actually `Future<SharedPreferenes>`.

Comment: I have the same issue.  My "sp" variable is a global variable which I can initialise and use (by retrieving setting and loading them into variables) but when I later use it from another route in my app (the settings page in which the user may change a setting) sp has become null.

Comment: I think I've just figured my problem out.  I was using a 'package' import reference in my 'settings' dart file to refer to the dart file with my global variable.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772318/flutter-dart-static-variables-lost-keep-getting-reinitialized

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I use the same approach as the original poster suggests i.e. I have a global variable (actually a static field in a class that I use for all such variables) which I initialise to the shared preferences something like this:

in `globals.dart`:

```
class App {      
  static SharedPreferences localStorage;
  static Future init() async {
    localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
}
```

in `main.dart`:

```
void main() {
  start();
}

Async.Future start() async {
  await App.init();
  localStorage.set('userName','Bob');
  print('User name is: ${localStorage.get('userName)'}');  //prints 'Bob'
}
```

The above worked fine but I found that if I tried to use `App.localStorage` from another dart file e.g. `settings.dart` it would not work because `App.localStorage` was null but I could not understand how it had become null.

Turns out the problem was that the import statement in `settings.dart` was `import 'package:<packagename>/src/globals.dart';` when it should have been `import 'globals.dart;`.

Answer (score 8):

@iBob101 's answer is good, but still, you have to wait before you use the SharedPreferences for the first time.

The whole point is NOT to `await` for your SharedPreferences and be sure that it will always be NOT NULL.

Since you'll have to wait anyway let's do it in the main() method:

```
class App {      
  static SharedPreferences localStorage;
  static Future init() async {
    localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
}
```

And the main method:

```
void main() async{
  await SharedPref.initSharedPref();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

the line `await SharedPref.initSharedPref();` takes ~100ms to execute. This is the only drawback as far as I can see.

But you definitely know that in every place in the app your sharedPreferenes instance in NOT NULL and ready for accessing it:

```
String s = App.localStorage.getString(PREF_MY_STRING_VALUE);
```

I think it's worthwhile

Comment: In newer version of Flutter, if you got an error due to adding async await on `main()`, just add this statement `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` in start of `main()` function

Comment: Need to add `late` to avoid CTE like `static late SharedPreferences localStorage;`

Comment: I don't know why `shared_preferences` isn't available synchronously by default. That's how User Defaults works on iOS. It's worth a slight startup delay to not have code filled with Futures!

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest way is to retrieve `SharedPreferences` in `main` method and pass it to `MyApp` as a dependency:

```dart
void main() async {
  // Takes ~50ms to get in iOS Simulator.
  final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
      await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  runApp(MyApp(sharedPreferences: sharedPreferences));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

  const MyApp({Key key, this.sharedPreferences})
      : assert(sharedPreferences != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // You can access shared preferences via widget.sharedPreferences
    return ...
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

I made a simple way to using this PrefUtil class:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class PrefUtil {
  static late final SharedPreferences preferences;
  static bool _init = false;
  static Future init() async {
    if (_init) return;
    preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _init = true;
    return preferences;
  }

  static setValue(String key, Object value) {
    switch (value.runtimeType) {
      case String:
        preferences.setString(key, value as String);
        break;
      case bool:
        preferences.setBool(key, value as bool);
        break;
      case int:
        preferences.setInt(key, value as int);
        break;
      default:
    }
  }

static Object getValue(String key, Object defaultValue) {
    switch (defaultValue.runtimeType) {
      case String:
        return preferences.getString(key) ?? "";
      case bool:
        return preferences.getBool(key) ?? false;
      case int:
        return preferences.getInt(key) ?? 0;
      default:
        return defaultValue;
    }
  }
}
```

In `main.dart`:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  PrefUtil.init();
  .....
```

Save it like:

```
PrefUtil.setValue("isLogin", true);
```

Get the value like:

```
PrefUtil.getValue("isLogin", false) as bool
```

By this, it will initialize only once and get it where ever you need.

Comment: Hi @Shailendra Madda is this one of the best way to initialise SharedPreferences at root level, which will make it globally available to **read** or **write** the value.

In addition to above solution, to remove any value

`static Object removeValue(String key) {
    return preferences.remove(key);
  }`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to render the loading screen while waiting for `SharedPreferences` to be intialized for the first time in a singleton-like class. After that, you can access it synchronously inside the children.

#### local_storage.dart

```
class LocalStorage {
  static late final SharedPreferences instance;

  static bool _init = false;
  static Future init() async {
    if (_init) return;
    instance = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _init = true;
    return instance;
  }
}
```

#### app_page.dart

```
final Future _storageFuture = LocalStorage.init();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: _storageFuture,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      Widget child;
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        child = MyPage();
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        child = Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
      } else {
        child = Text('Loading...');
      }
      return Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: child),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

#### my_page.dart

```
return Text(LocalStorage.instance.getString(kUserToken) ?? 'Empty');
```

Answer (score 1):

1. call shared prefs on startup of a **stateful** main app (we call ours a initState() override of a StatefulWidget after super.initState())
2. after shared prefs inits, set the value to a field on main (ex: String _someKey)
3. ***inject*** this field into any child component
4. You can the call setState() on _someKey at you leisure and it will persist to children injected with your field