# Globals in Flutter States

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-redux

Is it bad practice to use globals for state management in Flutter? I've come across a few different methodologies (ex: Redux) that seem like quite a bit of work to integrate with Firebase Cloud Firestore. Wondering what the downfalls would be to essentially manage my state with key value pairs using globals such as something like this:

[Globals in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29182581/5896354)

Comment: Consider explaining what you want to do instead. [Your question may fall into the xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Redux isn't that much work and it helps keeping your architecture clean.