# Good or Bad: Declaring main method async in Dart / Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I declare one global variable in the entire app - `SharedPreferences prefs`, and initialize it in `main` method.

However, `SharedPreferences` initialization returns a `Future` - hence I tried awaiting for it to be resolved in `main` closure of the app:

```dart
SharedPreferences prefs;

void main() async {
  prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

And it worked well. I currently use this method in my 2 apps in production, and it just occurred to me that making `main` method asynchronous might not be right.

In the end I have 2 questions:

- How does `main` method gets invoked and how it works in general in Dart / Flutter?
- Will making `main` method of the app asynchronous bring unexpected behaviour? (it hasn't so far)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> How does main method gets invoked and how it works in general in Dart / Flutter?

The Dart VM (or the runtime in AOT mode) looks for and executes a function named `main`.  After `main` returns, the VM will wait for pending asynchronous operations to complete before exiting.  The [Asynchronous programming](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures#async-await) article on the official Dart website has an example that demonstrates this:

> 7. When `main()` has finished executing, the asynchronous functions can resume execution. First, the future returned by `gatherNewsReports()` completes. Then `printDailyNewsDigest()` continues executing, printing the news.
> 8. When the `printDailyNewsDigest()` function body finishes executing, the future that it originally returned completes, and the app exits.

(Note that the [`exit` function](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-io/exit.html) will cause immediate termination without any waiting.)

---

> Will making main method of the app asynchronous bring unexpected behaviour? (it hasn't so far)

No.  First, you should keep in mind that the `async` keyword is *not* what makes a function asynchronous.  The `async` keyword simply enables the use of the `await` keyword (which itself is syntactic sugar for registering a `Future.then` callback) and (mostly) requires that the function be declared to return a `Future`. (I say "mostly" because returning `void` instead of `Future<void>` is allowed, although `dartanalyzer` will complain about that too if the [`avoid_void_async` lint](http://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_void_async.html) is enabled.)

Your application will inherently be asynchronous once you invoke *any* asynchronous function.  When you invoke an asynchronous function, you either:

- Wait for it to complete (via `await` or `Future.then`).  The caller is then asynchronous too.
- The asynchronous operation is unawaited ("fire-and-forget").  But this still means that `main` can return with asynchronous operations still pending.

Either way, your application must wait before terminating (assuming that it didn't encounter abnormal termination from an uncaught exception or `exit`).

Since your `main` function uses `await`, you don't even have a choice about marking it `async`.

Comment: Good piece of information. As my app grows, I've found myself needing to make asynchronous calls from the main method. Nothing bad happened but I always wondered if it would break something somewhere along the line.

Comment: The official document provide example changing main method to async method.[Working with futures: async and await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await)

Comment: @KexiHe That doesn't conflict with anything that I wrote.  I never said that `main` shouldn't be marked `async` or shouldn't return a `Future`.

Answer (score 6):

Good one from @jamesdlin .

A literal answer for your question

> How does main method gets invoked and how it works in general in Dart
>   / Flutter?

For Android apps, Dart entry point is invoked via `DartExecutor`. You can take a look at here: [DartExecutor class](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/904cfc4fe3631103c656ba617d9768a832d3622a/shell/platform/android/io/flutter/embedding/engine/dart/DartExecutor.java)

There is a brief document, how you can manually do what FlutterApplication does for you: 
[wiki/Experimental:-Launch-Flutter-with-non-main-entrypoint](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Experimental:-Launch-Flutter-with-non-main-entrypoint)

Classes you want to look for, if you want to dig deeper: `FlutterApplication`, `FlutterActivity`, `FlutterMain` .