# Return Future value

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use SharedPreferences to store persistently locale value. My code looks like this:

```
  Locale locale = const Locale('en');

  Locale getLocale(){
    _sharedPreferencesServices.read('locale', String).then((value) {
      locale = Locale(value ?? 'en');
    });
    return locale;
  }
```

Is it possible to return locale value after it is assigned inside then function? I want to get locale to use it in following function:

```
class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context,WidgetRef ref) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'CarAlgo',
      locale: ref.watch(localeProvider).getLocale(),
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        S.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: S.delegate.supportedLocales,
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      scaffoldMessengerKey: scaffoldMessengerKey,
      theme: AppTheme().theme1,
      home: const MainPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what keeps you from doing exactly that? instead of `Locale getLocale` why not simply write Future<Locale> getLocale() and return the future?

Comment: I want to use it in the MaterialApp as following:
return MaterialApp(
      title: 'CarAlgo',
      locale: ref.watch(localeProvider).getLocale(),
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        S.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: S.delegate.supportedLocales,
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      scaffoldMessengerKey: scaffoldMessengerKey,
      theme: AppTheme().theme1,
      home: const MainPage(),
    );

Comment: Expand your question with these information and more, if possible, because it's not really clear where the problem is. If you need the value returned by the `read`, why don't you just put an `await` before it (like `var locale = await _sharedPrefs.read(...);` and make the `getLocale` an `async` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example 1

```
  Future<Locale> getLocale(){
    return _sharedPreferencesServices.read('locale', String).then((value) {
      return Locale(value ?? 'en');
    });
  }
```

Example 2

```
  Future<Locale> getLocale() async {
    var value = await _sharedPreferencesServices.read('locale', String);
    return Locale(value ?? 'en');
  }
```

However, reading your comment, your problem isn't how to properly write this function, but how to call this function inside the main method.

You can make it async (But also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56129121/good-or-bad-declaring-main-method-async-in-dart-flutter)).

```
void main() async {
   var locale = await <...>.getLocale();
   return MaterialApp(...);
}
```