# How to make a methodchannel call before everything in flutter?

Tags: flutter

In my project , my flutter module need to fetch some information from native with MethodChannel.

And I want this method channel call is returned before even the root widget display (because this widget will use this information to fetch data and display)

I have tried invoking before runApp in main(). but this call seems too early to work . And **I don't know whether is a bad idea to make main async**

Any other better way to do this kind of work?

```
    void main() async{
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      MethodChannel platform = const MethodChannel('flutter.km.methodchannel');
      var nativeInfo = await platform.invokeMethod('getNativeInfo');
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your use of async-await. This question on stackoverflow has detailed information in the link below. please look there.

[Good or Bad: Declaring main method async in Dart / Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56129121/good-or-bad-declaring-main-method-async-in-dart-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with invoking a MethodChannel inside main() is that on the native side your 'GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register()' call hasn't probably being made yet, so the channel hasn't yet been established.