# Best practice and performance for global variables

Tags: performance, flutter, dart

I need to store some data that should be available everywhere on my application. So far, I know three methods to do it:

- Create a special file to make variable global ([Global Variables in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182581/global-variables-in-dart/29182641#29182641))
- Use shared preference (here I just want to access the data not necessarily to store it forever)
- And InheritedWidget

I would like to know which solution (or another one that I don't know) is the best in matters of performance and easy to implement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An `InheritedWidget` might be the best and cleaner way because:

- it gives you the advantage of scoping your variable (I know, you need them globe, so that's not your concern, for now).
- you can rebuild it under some circumstances via the `updateShouldNotify`. When rebuilding an `InheritedWidget` you rebuild all the widgets that are referencing its properties.
- it's cleaner than global variables, because you have more control over them and you can also implement some "global" methods that leverage some private variables. It's still a class, after all.
- the access has `O(1)` complexity since Flutter indexes `InheritedWidget` implementation, allowing efficient access through the `ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType` method from `context`.

That said, `SharedPreferences` is a big no since you'd be doing a lot of disk I/O, which has a lot worse performance than operating in RAM. Plus, you'd need a lot of boilerplate to manage the temporary nature of your variables.

As for global variables, I think they don't give you the same agility of an `InheritedWidget` and I don't think that they're a good practice.

Talking about `InheritedWidget`, for "dynamic" stuff you might not use it plain, since its variables *should* be immutable (the class is marked as `immutable`, so all of your members should be final).

A clean way to work around this is well explained [here](https://flutterbyexample.com/set-up-inherited-widget-app-state/). Basically the `AppState` are your global variables.

**EDIT** as @Rémi Rousselet pointed out, telling that `ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType` has `O(1)` complexity is a bit of a stretch, since the lookup is performed on an `HashMap`, which has `O(1)` complexity for the best case, `O(n)` in the worst case.

It's still an efficient way since it doesn't traverse the whole widget tree looking for it.

Comment: O(1) for InheritedWidgets is a bit of a lie. It doesn't traverse the widget tree, but it still looks into a hash map.
But yeah, I'll take InheritedWidgets over globals all the time.

Comment: Yeah you're right, O(1) is the best case scenario. I'm going to edit that, thanks!

Comment: InheritedWidget is awesome for global state, however, it's not recommended by any means to have a unique inherited widget because it will call ALL of the build methods. I generally use a root inherited widget for data that doesn't change that often, and then below that i use multiple inherited widgets with selective data