# How to get current font family value in flutter?

Tags: flutter, fonts

```
 return MaterialApp(
      title: 'title',
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'Times',
```

How do I get the defined fontfamily string value while on any page?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your font-family string a global variable using:

```
import 'globals.dart' as globals;
```

Please refer to the post below for a more detailed explanation

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29182641/8622829