# Flutter save data and use it through pages

Tags: flutter, dart, save, sharedpreferences, savechanges

On my app i would like to save some data as if they were settings. So I would like to found them in every page and widget of the app. I was thinking about shared preferences but I don't know if is the correct choice. 
Has someone any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: We're going to need more details to help you. Is this information you want to save permanently on the device, or just data you want to temporarily share across your app?

Comment: Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182581/global-variables-in-dart

Comment: just temporarily