# How to reload screen on future data

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-widget, future

I have `TabBarView` with six tabs.
I'm trying to show all the installed apps in first tab.

Even after `apps` is filled `CircularProgressIndicator` is displayed. Apps are listed once the first tab is revisited.

`AppScreenC` is called for first tab.

```
final model = AppModel();

class AppScreenC extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppScreenCState createState() => _AppScreenCState();
}

class _AppScreenCState extends State<AppScreenC> {
  List<Application> apps = model.loadedApps();
      
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => _buildApps();

  Widget _buildApps() => apps != null
      ? ListView.builder(
          itemCount: apps.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
              _buildRow(apps[index]))
      : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

  Widget _buildRow(ApplicationWithIcon app) {
    final saved = model.getApps().contains(app.apkFilePath);
    return ListTile(
      leading: Image.memory(app.icon, height: 40),
      trailing: saved
          ? Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.deepPurple[400])
          : Icon(Icons.check_circle_outline),
      title: Text(app.appName),
      onTap: () => setState(() => saved
          ? model.removeApp(app.apkFilePath)
          : model.addApp(app.apkFilePath)),
    );
  }
}
```

`AppModel` class has all the necessary methods.

```
  class AppModel{
  final _saved = Set<String>();
  List<Application> apps;

  AppModel() {
    loadApps();
  }

  Set<String> getApps() {
    return _saved;
  }

  addApp(String apkPath) {
    _saved.add(apkPath);
  }

  removeApp(String apkPath) {
    _saved.remove(apkPath);
  }

  loadApps() async {
    apps = await DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications(
        onlyAppsWithLaunchIntent: true,
        includeSystemApps: true,
        includeAppIcons: true);
    apps.sort((a, b) => a.appName.compareTo(b.appName));
  }

  loadedApps() => apps;
}
```

This is happening because `apps` is null, when the screen was called first time. It loads the apps in background. Upon visiting the screen again, apps are displayed.

Any help is welcome

Comment: Yeah, this is what I wanted. I'll try the same in my case

Comment: I tried the first example. I added `future = loadApps()` in `initState()` and added `FutureBuilder` to `build` of `AppScreenC`. Progress bar is displayed every time I visit first tab. Is it because of calling a `StatefulWidget` in `TabBarView`? My tab bar view looks like `TabBarView( children: [AppScreenC(), //Other tabs])`.

Comment: Second example is working perfectly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221074/discussion-between-shanthosh-and-pskink).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is calling `setState()` after your Function is done. You need to change loadedApp to return a `Future`:

```
class AppScreenC extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppScreenCState createState() => _AppScreenCState();
}

class _AppScreenCState extends State<AppScreenC> {
  @override
 void initState(){
 super.initState();
 model.loadApps().then((loadedApps){ //loadApps() will return apps and you don't need loadedApps() method anymore
 setState((){ //rebuilds the screen
  apps = loadedApps
   })});
}
      
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => _buildApps();

  Widget _buildApps() => apps != null
      ? ListView.builder(
          itemCount: apps.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
              _buildRow(apps[index]))
      : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

  Widget _buildRow(ApplicationWithIcon app) {
    final saved = model.getApps().contains(app.apkFilePath);
    return ListTile(
      leading: Image.memory(app.icon, height: 40),
      trailing: saved
          ? Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.deepPurple[400])
          : Icon(Icons.check_circle_outline),
      title: Text(app.appName),
      onTap: () => setState(() => saved
          ? model.removeApp(app.apkFilePath)
          : model.addApp(app.apkFilePath)),
    );
  }
}
```

And your `AppModel` will look like this:

```
class AppModel{
  final _saved = Set<String>();
  List<Application> apps;

  AppModel() {
    loadApps();
  }

  Set<String> getApps() {
    return _saved;
  }

  addApp(String apkPath) {
    _saved.add(apkPath);
  }

  removeApp(String apkPath) {
    _saved.remove(apkPath);
  }

  Future loadApps() async {
    apps = await DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications(
        onlyAppsWithLaunchIntent: true,
        includeSystemApps: true,
        includeAppIcons: true);
    apps.sort((a, b) => a.appName.compareTo(b.appName));
    return Future.value(apps);
  }

}
```

You can also use `FutureBuilder` as suggested in the comments

Comment: Thank you!!! for the answer. But this code shows `circularProgressIndicator` every time first tab is visited. To overcome that, I added a null check in loadApps().                    
`Future loadApps() async { if(apps == null) { // same code } return Future.value(apps); }`                                                                                             Is it right?

Comment: You have 2 options. you can define app as a global variable so when you visit this page (if already visited), then `app` is not null anymore and you don't need to run `loadApps()` anymore. You can also visit  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51738269/12828249 to learn how to preserve the screen state so that when you come back to this screen, you don't build the screen again and with that, you won't see the `circularProgressIndicator` if `apps` are not null

Comment: Will there be any performance issue by making app as a global variable

Comment: Not that I know of but you have to be careful not to change the value somewhere else in the app as global variables are accessible throughout the program. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182581/global-variables-in-dart for creating global variables

Comment: If it's constantly being reloaded or is accessed in too many widgets, then yes.  Otherwise, it should be fine.

Comment: Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10525602/12828249 for global variables disadvantages