# Flutter: save variable in class to show it in different widgets

Tags: flutter

I have a `provider` for which I use a `ChangeNotifier` with `notifyListeners()` so the UI updates with the changes.

This is a bit different because I don't need to update the UI, at least not in the same view. Example:
In page A I change the value of my global var and in page B (I need to move from one page to another) I show my var.

So I have something like this:

```
class MyGlobalClass {
  String test = "";

  changeTest() {
    test = "New";
  }
}

final myGlobalClass = MyGlobalClass();
```

The problem comes more from the value than the UI. The value still not updated when I inspect the object.

Am I force to use always a `provider` for these cases and pass the `context`? Because I also need to modify some global vars in the beginning where I don't have any context yet.

isn't this the same approach? https://stackoverflow.com/a/29182641/4858133

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only needed to make the global var `static`