# How to setState() in StreamBuilder()?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
  return ListView(
      children:
          snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data =
        document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
    // setState(() {
    //   allCalWorkout += data['totalCal'];
    // });
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: ListTile(
          onTap: () {},
          title: Text(data['nameWorkout']),
          subtitle: Text(
              'set: ${data['set']} calories:${data['totalCal']}'),
          trailing: IconButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                // print(document.id);
                await delWorkout(document.id);
                setState(() {
                  _workout = getAllWorkout();
                });
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.red))),
    );
  }).toList());
```

[image: My Screen]

I want to sum all the calories in firebase name is "totalCal" and also how to store the total variable for passing to another page.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sum = data['totalCal'].fold(0, (sum, element) => sum + element['totalCal']!);
      print('sum2 = $sum2');
```

I don't its will work or not, but if you use fold method then you can sum the value

Comment: has error "NoSuchMethodError: 'fold'
Dynamic call of null.
Receiver: 200
Arguments:[0,Instance of '(dynamic, dynamic) => dynamic']

Comment: fold will work in list. I think if you insert data in list then you can use fold

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html), StreamBuilder will listen to changes in order to set its state, so the state is managed by new events that happen:

> Widget rebuilding is scheduled by each interaction, using State.setState, but is otherwise decoupled from the timing of the stream.

The [FlutterFire documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes) includes an example on how to listen to Firestore for events that can be used to update the widget. The same documentation page has a [guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#updating-documents) on how to update a value in the Firestore document with the `update` method (in this case your `totalCal` amount resulting from adding all the calories). I followed the example and can confirm it works.

As for how to preserve your `totalCal` value between views, you can do this by storing this variable in a library file which is imported into all of your views, and then setting the value after doing a sum of all the calories will update it everywhere. You can review this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182581/) for more details.