# Flutter update Widgets automatically based on parameter changes

Tags: flutter

I have a **[global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29182641/12695188)** and I want to refresh my Widgets automatically (without using `setState` each time) whenever its value changes.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `provider` for that [link](https://pub.dev/packages/provider),

1. You start your root Build method in the app with:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(  // Multi means you can have more providers if you need
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (context) => MyStateClass()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(....
```

2. Now you can place all the data you need to share in the MyStateClass() and place underlying Widgets inside:

```
 Consumer<MyStateClass>(builder: (context, state, child) {

      // your code here - return(SomeOtherWidget());
    })
```

3. or inside your Build methods:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   MyStateClass state = Provider.of<MyStateClass>(context);
   // ... TODO  ... return (Widget)
```